# Jest createSpyObj

Tags: jestjs

With Chai, you can create a spy object as follows:

```
chai.spy.object([ 'push', 'pop' ]);
```

With jasmine, you can use:

```
jasmine.createSpyObj('tape', ['play', 'pause', 'stop', 'rewind']);
```

What's the Jest equivalent?

Context: I am currently migrating a (typescript) Jasmine tests to (typescript) Jest. The migration guide is basically useless in this case: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/migration-guide.html As with any relatively new tech, there's nothing that can easily be found in the docs about this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've written a very quick `createSpyObj` function for jest, to support the old project. Basically ported from Jasmine's implementation.

```js
export const createSpyObj = (baseName, methodNames): { [key: string]: Mock<any> } => {
    let obj: any = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < methodNames.length; i++) {
        obj[methodNames[i]] = jest.fn();
    }

    return obj;
};
```

Comment: what is ...Mock<any> doing? is it just the importing like 'import Mock = jest.Mock'?

Comment: @acekizzy I can confirm that it is `jest.Mock`.  It allows you to mock the methods like this: `let obj = createSpyObj('', ['run']); obj.run.mockReturnValue(someValue);`.  Note that in this implementation the baseName doesn't do anything.  It would be nicer if type safety could be added.

Answer (score 8):

```
const video = {
  play() {
    return true;
  },
};

module.exports = video;
```

And the test:

```
const video = require('./video');

test('plays video', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(video, 'play');
  const isPlaying = video.play();

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(isPlaying).toBe(true);

  spy.mockReset();
  spy.mockRestore();
});
```

Docs found here: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname

There is also jest.fn()

```
const mockFn = jest.fn();
  mockFn();
  expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalled();

  // With a mock implementation:
  const returnsTrue = jest.fn(() => true);
  console.log(returnsTrue()); // true;
```

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestfnimplementation

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Max Millington answer I found solution with `jest.fn()` method:

1. Create mocked object:

`const tape: any = {};`

2. Add required method(s) for mocked object

`tape['play'] = jest.fn();`

3. You can spyOn mocked methods but first assign it to real object, for example I'm using component instance:

   ```
   // GIVEN
   comp.realTape = tape

   // WHEN
   spyOn( comp.realTape , 'play')
   comp.method()

   // THEN
   expect(comp.realTape.play).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @David for your answer!

Even today it is not as easy to find a built in solution for this.
I modified your example as basename is not used in your example.
When using this object in a test I always had to cast it as unknown as [Type] wich i did not want to.

```
export const createSpyObj = <T>(methodNames): { [key: string]:jest.Mock<any> } & { spyObj: T } => {

  const obj: { [key: string]: jest.Mock<any> } & { spyObj: T } = { 
spyObj: null } as any;

  for (let i = 0; i < methodNames.length; i++) {
     obj[methodNames[i]] = jest.fn();
  }

  obj.spyObj= obj as T;
  return obj;
};
```

with this code I can use pass the spyObj in the constructor of my tested Service.

```
const injectedService = createSpyObj<InjectedService>(['something']);

injectedService.something.mockReturnValue(true);

const serviceToBeTested = new ServiceToBeTested(injectedService.spyObj);
expect(injectedService.something).toBeCalled();
```

One caveat is that intellisense does not work for methodNames anymore.

Answer (score -1):

`David`'s answer helped to get me on the right track.  I modified it to work with ionic-mocks (https://github.com/stonelasley/ionic-mocks) in my Ionic3/Angular4 project.

In my test "helper" class, I have this:

```
export function  createSpyObj (baseName: string, methodNames: string[]): { [key: string]: jasmine.Spy } {
  const obj: any = {}
  for (let i: number = 0; i < methodNames.length; i++) {
    obj[methodNames[i]] = jasmine.createSpy(baseName, () => {})
  }
  return obj
}
```

Then I'm able to use it as such in my test/spec file.  I inject the provider in question as:

```
{ provide: AlertController, useFactory: () => AlertControllerMock.instance() },
```

And until ionic-mocks is compatible with Jest, I have to copy over the mocks I want (which use `createSpyObj`):

```
class AlertMock {
  public static instance (): any {
    const instance: any = createSpyObj('Alert', ['present', 'dismiss'])
    instance.present.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve())
    instance.dismiss.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve())

    return instance
  }
}

class AlertControllerMock {
  public static instance (alertMock?: AlertMock): any {

    const instance: any = createSpyObj('AlertController', ['create'])
    instance.create.and.returnValue(alertMock || AlertMock.instance())

    return instance
  }
}
```