# TypeError: jasmine.createSpyObj is not a function

Tags: angular, jasmine

I need to unit test a component method that does not return a Promise, but internally calls a method in a service that does, and so unit test execution returns immediately to the 'it' block. This results in objects that I am supposed to look at for certain values to not yet be assigned. [Angular documentation suggests that I use a Spy object](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-async-service). This seems to be exactly what I need. Unfortunately, even the most basic of unit tests won't let me create a Spy object.

The following code...

```
describe('my unit test', () => {

    var myService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        myService = jasmine.createSpyObj('myService', ['myMethodOne', 'myMethodTwo']);
        myService.myMethodOne();
    });

    it("my service test", () => {
        expect(myService.myMethodOne).toBeDefined();
        expect(myService.myMethodOne).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

Fails with...

```
>npm test

> iwp-app@0.0.0 test D:\Users\brock\Source
> jest

 FAIL  component.spec.ts
  my unit test
    × my service test (41ms)

  ● my unit test › my service test

    TypeError: jasmine.createSpyObj is not a function

      at component.spec.ts:29:25
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:26)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:128:39)
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:32)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:138:43)
      at Object.testBody.length (node_modules/jest-zone-patch/index.js:50:27)

  ● my unit test › my service test

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'myMethodOne' of undefined

      at create-template.component.spec.ts:34:22
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:26)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:128:39)
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:32)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:138:43)
      at Object.testBody.length (node_modules/jest-zone-patch/index.js:50:27)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.36s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Comment: You seem to be using Jest, not the default Karma/Jasmine config. Please give a [mcve] detailing the test setup.

Comment: @brock: what jonrsharpe is saying is that there are probably elements missing in the MWE.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem There certainly could be, but down voting because I didn't ask the question the right way is discouraging. Like I said, total noob, and I don't know anything about the environment that I was handed a script of steps to setup. I was upfront about that, but still someone got all holier than thou on me because I didn't know what I didn't know. That's poor community management. And the icing on the cake is that same someone probably deleted my previous comment which also criticised the down voting. I don't care what your rep score is, you can be wrong. Deal with it constructively.

Comment: Well I did not downvote the question :). Like the saying goes "*Assumptions are the mother of all problems*" (well the quote is a bit harder, but I think the language is inappropriate here :). I think the dowvote is more about the fact that you did not really react to the comment by providing the configuration.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Sorry, if you felt that last part was directed at you. It wasn't, it was directed at "someone" and there is no evidence as to who "someone" is. Granted, it could be you, but from your previous comment I honesty didn't think it was.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I _now_ understand why "someone" thought it should be down voted, but I disagree with that action. My question was upfront about my knowledge of the environment I'm working in. Instead of just saying "MCVE", a better approach would have been to help me improve the question. It's win-win. I would have learned something and the community would have gotten a better question. As it stands, I still have no clue how to make it a MCVE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jest doesn't have a function named createSpyObj() like default jasmine has , please visit this link [Jest createSpyObj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45304270/jest-createspyobj/45309677)
which is a custom createSpyObj function in jest or just switch to jasmine instead