# How to get code coverage inside a callback using jest?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3, callback, jestjs, google-geocoder

I'm having trouble with code coverage and can't figure it out. I am using google geocoding API to query coordinates where response is returned inside callback function. 
Jest is used for testing.

This is the testable call with callback:

```
const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({address: address}, (results, status) => {
  // want to get coverage in this block
  // expected test results are OK and logging shows right results
});
```

This is the test. Because google.maps is not available by default when testing, I found such solution:

```
it('test', () => {
  const constructorSpy = spyOn(google.maps, 'Geocoder');
  const geocoder = createSpyObj('Geocoder', ['geocode']);
  constructorSpy.and.returnValue(geocoder);
  geocoder.geocode = jest.fn((adr, callback) => callback(response, 'OK'));
  // expected results that are all OK
});
```

createSpyObj https://stackoverflow.com/a/45319913/1756136:

```
const createSpyObj = (baseName, methodNames): { [key: string]: Mock<any> } => {
  let obj: any = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < methodNames.length; i++) {
    obj[methodNames[i]] = jest.fn();
  }
  return obj;
};
```

And google.maps is defined in setupTests.js. When not testing, google.maps is available when react loads google map

```
window.google = {
  maps: {
    Geocoder: {},
    GeocoderStatus: {
      OK: 'OK'
    }
  }
};
```

Any ideas what I could try or look into? Only coverage is the problem, expected results are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code coverage is actually already working correctly with this implementation. Problem was that I wasn't accessing 'else' statements in 'if' clauses where there was only 'if' clause.

Also it's possible not to spy on, but define as a property and run your test:

```
it('test', () => {
  Object.defineProperty(google, 'maps', {
    value: {
      Geocoder: function () {
        return {
          geocode: jest.fn((adr, callback) => callback(response, 'OK'))
        }
      }
    }
  });
  // expect..
});
```