# mock a toPromise function in jest - got .toPromise is not a function

Tags: node.js, promise, jestjs, nestjs

I have an httpService from nestjs/common

and I am using like the following:

```
const response = await this.httpService.post(`${this.api}/${action}`, data).toPromise();
```

and in my jest spec file ( unit testing) . i am trying to mock this service

```
   httpServiceMock = {
      post: jest.fn()
    };

it('should start', async () => {

    const serviceResult = await service.start(data);

});
```

and I have got this error :

```
TypeError: this.httpService.post(...).toPromise is not a function
```

I am also trying to add a promise result like :

```
 const promise = Promise.resolve('result');
 httpServiceMock.post.mockResolvedValue(promise);
```

tried also :

```
it('should start', async () => {

    const mockObservable = Promise.resolve({
        toPromise: () => {
          console.log('toPromise called');
        }
      })

    httpServiceMock.post.mockImplementation(() => mockObservable);

    const serviceResult = await service.start();

});
```

**My question is how can I mock the promise and return a response or exception**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The return value [httpService.post](https://nestjs-doc.exceptionfound.com/classes/httpservice.html#post) needs to return an `Observable<AxiosResponse<T>>` which includes a property [toPromise](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html), which is a function. Your mock returns a resolved promise, whereas it needs to return a fake Observable.

The Observable is returned immediately, so the `post` implementation can just return a raw value, but the `toPromise` needs to return a promise.

Return the correct shaped object to get rid of this error:

```
const mockObservable = {
  toPromise: () => Promise.resolve('result')
}
httpServiceMock.post.mockImplementation(() => mockObservable);
```

Comment: Have you checked that the `httpService.post` uses the mock, and not the real function? You could try putting a console log after the `const response = await this.httpService.post(`${this.api}/${action}`, data).toPromise();` line, e.g. `console.log(this.httpService.post`)

Comment: If you haven't already, you will need to import the httpService module, and mock it with `jest.mock`

Comment: Your `mockObservable` probably shouldn't return a promise

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that could not be solved by accepted answer. So I bring here another solution just in case it could help someone else.

If you have jasmine, just use `jasmine.createSpyObj()`. If not, here is what I needed to do :

First, I implemented a `jasmine.createSpyObj()` equivalent (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45319913/5444485) with little modifications) :

```
export class TestUtilsService {
  static createSpyObj (baseName:string, methodNames:string[]): SpyObject {
    let obj: any = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < methodNames.length; i++) {
      obj[methodNames[i]] = jest.fn();
    }
    return {[baseName]:()=>obj};
  };
}

export class SpyObject {
  [key: string]: ()=>{[key:string]:jest.Mock} ;
}
```

Then I used it in my unit test :

```
const spyHttpClient: SpyObject = TestUtilsService.createSpyObj('get',['toPromise']);
```

Add it in test module providers :

```
{provide: HttpClient, useValue: spyHttpClient}
```

Finally, mock the toPromise implementation in order to return a mocked response :

```
const mockedResponse = {...};
spyHttpClient.get().toPromise.mockImplementationOnce(()=>Promise.resolve(mockedResponse));
await service.myRealMethodThatCallsHttpClient();
expect(service.someUpdatedProp).toBeTruthy();
```

Please notice parenthesis after method get.

Answer (score 0):

"A Jar of Clays" solution didn't work for me (I got mockImplementation is not a function), but this worked:

```
    const mockPromise = {
        toPromise: () => Promise.resolve(ical)
    }

    mockHttpService.get = jest.fn( () => {return mockPromise});
```