# what is the equivalent of jasmine.createSpyObj() for jest?

Tags: jestjs, karma-jasmine

What is the equivalent of the below code in Jest.

```js
let mockHeroService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getHeros', 'addHero', 'deleteHero']);
```

I would like to use it the testBed.

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    {
       provide: HeroService,
       useValue: mockHeroService         
    }
  ]
});
```

My understanding is that, with jest, you can only spy on one method of a service like

```js
const spy = jest.spyOn(HeroService, 'getHeros');
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest createSpyObj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45304270/jest-createspyobj)

Comment: @jonrsharpe now that I understood how it works, the link you provided would have the answer to my question. However, the way people have answered is not clear and straightforward for someone learning Jest. Thank you because I see also other information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no equivalent because it doesn't have much uses. Jest is focused on modular JavaScript and generates auto-mocks (stubs) with `jest.mock` and `jest.createMockFromModule`.

The problem with auto-mocks is that they result in unspecified set of functions that behave differently from original ones and can make the code that uses them to work incorrectly or silently fail.

A mock with no implementation can be defined as:

```
let mockHeroService = { getHeros: jest.fn(), ... };
```

Most times some implementation is expected:

```
let mockHeroService = { getHeros: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(...), ... };
```

Comment: thank you so much for saving the day. That was the only piece missing. It is also an entry point for me with Jest. Thank you for saving the day.

Comment: How about if there is a type associated with jasmine.createSpyObj  eg: jasmine.createSpy<HttpClient>

Comment: @Arun-G jest.fn can be expected to be a generic either, https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#jestfnimplementation . Depends on the case which way would cause less type problem and keep type safety, probably in this case `let mockHeroService: jest.Mocked<HeroService> = { getHeros: jest.fn<HeroService['getHeros']>()...`